# Is it correct to use the verb dienen with ist?

Tags: phrase, perfect-tense

I don't understand why we use ''ist'' in this sentence:

> Damit ist mir gedient.

Because it is phrase or something? And is it the only way we use ''ist'' with the verb ''dienen''?

*Sorry guys im new. I know the meaning I just don't understand function of ''ist'' and ''damit'' in this sentence, it just doesn't make sense to me. Is it just because this is a Redewendung or is there some rule that I might have missed?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of sentence at all? Add more context please.

Comment: sorry im new and trying desperately to put this sentence into a logic so i forgot to write that. yes i know the meaning just don't know the rule the logical reason behind it why we use ''ist'' while its partizip 2 form ''habe gedient''

Comment: Because that is passive. It would well go as _Damit war mir gedient._

Comment: oh thank you, so it is zustandpassiv right? if its not we should use gedient werden?

Answer (score 2):

> Danke. **Mit dieser Antwort** ist mir gedient.
>
> Danke für **die Antwort**. **Damit** ist mir gedient.

*Damit* is a backreference to something in a previous sentence, while adding the preposition *mit*. That preposition is required by that phrase *jemandem mit X gedient sein*. It means *X is what I wanted*.

It's *Zustandspassiv* of *dienen* but you should really take it as a fixed phrase. Desconstructing it leads to *dienen* as a state, and that's odd. Usually one would use *bedient* for states of *dienen/bedienen*. Not in this case.

Answer (score -1):

This is an idiom ('Redewendung') <-> 'This serves my turn.'

You use this sentence, if you're ok/content with an outcome.

More context would be useful.

Comment: _"this is an idiom ('Redewendung')"_ Not really. It's perfectly OK regarding usage of correct grammar.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thing they've got a point. The phrase is perfectly grammatical, but still has idiomatic meaning going further than the literal meaning. _Damit ist mir geholfen_ means, quite literally, that I got helped; _damit ist mir gedient_ usually does not imply servantship, but satisfaction of a request, IMHO.